# Multipart upload to Amazon S3 overwrites the last part

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm following the documentation found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html) about doing multipart upload with the .NET client library.

The issue I'm having is that each part sent to S3 is overwriting the last part. So in other words my pieces are 10kb each (tried 5mb at a time too) and each upload overwrites the previous. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I've got

```
var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(_s3Client);
var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = "mybucket",
        InputStream = stream,
        StorageClass = S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy,
        PartSize = stream.Length,//stream is 10,000 bytes at a time
        Key = fileName
    };
```

**Edit**

Here's working code for doing the multipart upload

```
public UploadPartResponse UploadChunk(Stream stream, string fileName, string uploadId, List<PartETag> eTags, int partNumber, bool lastPart)
{
    stream.Position = 0;

    //Step 1: build and send a multi upload request
    if (partNumber == 1)
    {
        var initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = _settings.Bucket,
            Key = fileName
        };

        var initResponse = _s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);
        uploadId = initResponse.UploadId;
    }

    //Step 2: upload each chunk (this is run for every chunk unlike the other steps which are run once)
    var uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
                        {
                            BucketName = _settings.Bucket,
                            Key = fileName,
                            UploadId = uploadId,
                            PartNumber = partNumber,
                            InputStream = stream,
                            IsLastPart = lastPart,
                            PartSize = stream.Length
                        };

    var response = _s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest);

    //Step 3: build and send the multipart complete request
    if (lastPart)
    {
        eTags.Add(new PartETag
        {
            PartNumber = partNumber,
            ETag = response.ETag
        });

        var completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = _settings.Bucket,
            Key = fileName,
            UploadId = uploadId,
            PartETags = eTags
        };

        try
        {
            _s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
        }
        catch
        {
            //do some logging and return null response
            return null;
        }
    }

    response.ResponseMetadata.Metadata["uploadid"] = uploadRequest.UploadId;
    return response;
}
```

If you have a stream that is broken up into 10 chunks you will be hitting this method 10 times, on the first chunk you will hit step 1 & 2, chunks 2-9 only step 2 and on the last only step 3. Your need to send back to your client the upload id and the etag for each response. At step 3 you will need to provide the etag for all pieces or else it will put together the file on S3 without 1 more pieces. On my client side I had a hidden field where I persisted the etag list (comma delimited).

Comment: Thanks, your code in the edit helped me to implement a chunked file upload to S3. In your code though, just after the opening brace of `if (lastPart)`, the `eTags.Add()` call should come before the if statement, I believe, in order to accumulate the different eTags from each chunk upload.

Comment: Does stream.Length works?

Comment: My stream is not seekable. In that case, i can't get the stream.Length or stream.Position working. It is throwing exceptions. I tried removing those parts and got 'Base stream of PartialWrapperStream must be seekable' error in this line _s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this code sets up is a request that will upload an object with only one part because you pass in a stream and set the part size to the length of the whole stream.

The intention of using the TransferUtility is you would give it a large stream or file path and set part size to the increments you want the stream broke down to. You can also leave PartSize blank which will use a default part size.

Comment: That makes sense. I was able to get their "low level" api example working to achieve the multipart upload using multiple chunks coming from a client.